# Dequeueing TableViewCells from Storyboard Prototype cells?

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uikit

I have defined a tableView in code within my main ViewController class.  I have added that to the main view and also defined a custom tableViewCell in a swift file.  I have setup a basic app displaying some datasource information in the single textLabel that comes default with a subclassed `UITableViewCell`.  However, now I want to design a slightly more complicated UI in Interface builder.  My ViewController is defined in the Main Storyboard.  How do I sync up my pre-existing tableViewCell with a `prototype cell` view element in storyboard? Filling in the Cell Identifier and the Custom Class with my class, as well as calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with that identifier and casting the result to my custom type does not seem to give me a cell with the properties loaded up in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code you are using?

It should look something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    return cell    
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  It seems the problem was that I instantiated my TableView all in code and I only wanted to work on UI design in storyboard with respect to the cell.  So I dropped a TableViewCell (called prototype in Storyboard?!) and synced it up with my code in the usual ways.  For reasons most likely to do with the improper hierarchy of a tableviewCell  being embedded in a normal UIView instead of a tableview.  Anyway, the solution for me was to opt for defining the tableview in the storyboard.